# Renaming multiple PDF files according to info in XML file

Tags: xml, file, pdf, rename, file-rename

I encountered the following challenge and I unfortunately can't seem to find a way on how to get started with it:

I have a folder containing around **one thousand PDF-files**, each named `123456.pdf`, where the total number of characters varies between 4 and 6 but they are always just numbers.

I furthermore have an XML file, which contains different tags, which include a tag - let's call it `<Test> </Test>`, that contains an **ID**, which was used to create the PDF-filename and the **original filename**. E.g.:

```
<Test ID="123456" OriginalFilename="abc123def.pdf"></Test>
```

How could I start in order to rename all my PDF-files to the original filenames according to the information given in the XML-file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

I've actually worked out an uncommon but fine solution:

I have imported the XML file into excel, deleting all columns except the **ID** and **OriginalFilename**. I then proceeded as shown here:

https://benholland.me/tutorials/2011/11/11/rename-multiple-files-using-excel-in-windows.html

Worked beautifully!